# How to walk throuh youtube?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am curious to know what would be the most efficient way to walk the youtube website. My goal is to eventually index all videos on youtube (hypothetically) and the only way I can think of is to go channel by channel indexing all of the videos. I am not very familiar with the v3 APi, so if there is a better way to accomplish this, please let me know. This gives rise to a few problems I can think of:

1. Where to begin? Channels and videos are accessed using random string IDs, so if I simply start with IDs beginning with 'A' I am going to run into a lot of null values. Not sure how IDs are assigned, but this also may keep the indexing in a certain segment/section of video types if it is based on the ID alphanumerics.
2. I am hoping to move methodically through the youtube directory, trying to avoid accidently indexing the same channel/video.
3. Should I somehow seperate the videos into groups and request them based on other parameters? A grouped scheme may be easier to work with, update, etc.

I won't know if the video has anything I am interested in indexing before accessing it.

Comment: You'll probably be blacklisted/throttled by Youtube's servers before you come anywhere close to scraping it all…

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand that there are way too many videos for you to do this without having access to the stack directly, which you do not have and will not get.

As to automate the selection of video's, you can try to use the video ID's.
They are 11 characters long, consisting of only "**a**-**z A**-**Z _** and **-** " . So that would reduce (*still is 54 to the power of 11*) the indexing/scanning if a video exists. Then save that ID (with related info) and move on.

Not a perfect option, but best I can see with your options and requirements.